# How to return Many "Await" in one Promise

Tags: reactjs, async-await, es6-promise

I have a react async function `export const EcgSaveDpcRequestSPService = async (dataItem, filesData) => {`
Inside it I have 2 awaits Posting to 2 SharePoint lists then an async forEach `dataItem.dpcUpFiles.forEach(async (file, index) => {` That has 3 awaits that Posts to other Sharepoint lists. some of the awaits need results from Post results before them.

I had a :`Promise.resolve(..` that fired only when all the awaits finish
After adding some more code, the processing goes to the `Promise.resolve(..` right after the first await in the loop.
I can't tell if there was an error or not because none of the `catch` get to be processed.

How can organise all the Posts so only when all of them are done, I can return from the function?
If there is an error, It should reject right away.

Comment: `.forEach()` is not promise aware and will not pause its loop for `await`.  So, get rid of `.forEach()` and use a regular `for` loop.  There are pretty much no reasons to use `.forEach()` any more.  For any further help, please add a meaningful section of code to your question so we can see exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

you can write it like this

```
try {
    for (const file of dataItem.dpcUpFiles) {
        await yourAsyncFunction();
    }
    // all done
} catch ((error) => {
    // failed
});
```